# Unable to use SUBSTR function while using left join in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Please I am trying to execute the below query and i keep getting the error

> ORA-00904: "B"."SUBSTR": invalid identifier

```
select A.column1,B.SUBSTR(TRAN_REF,11,10),A.column2,B.column1,B.column2
from Table1 A
left join Table2 B
on A.column1= B.SUBSTR(SRC_TRAN_REF,11,10)
```

Comment: Built-in functions don't have a schema and don't require any qualifiers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table alias is part of the column, not of the function name:

```
select A.column1,SUBSTR(B.TRAN_REF,11,10),A.column2,B.column1,B.column2
from Table1 A
left join Table2 B
on A.column1= SUBSTR(B.SRC_TRAN_REF,11,10)
```